# Unable to return value from a function that calls another function with a closure

Tags: swift

I’m having trouble getting 2 functions to play nicely and return the expected result.

I have a function that returns a bool. And this function has to remain unchanged.  The second one I can change to fit my needs.  I have a feeling I’m missing something really small and nit understand the syntax.

These functions have been simplified and renamed, that’s not actually what they are called.

```
func isUserHome() -> Bool {
     // I need to call the next function and return a Boolean that it returns

     return checkUserSomething()
Or 
     checkUserSomething() {
         return success
     }
}

func checkUserSomething(completion: @escaping (_ success: Bool) -> Void) {
    Client.get() { (response) in
        if response.isHome {
            completion(true)
        } else {
            completion(false)
        }
    }
}
```

In the end I need to call isUserHome() and do something.  And I have to do that because of other dependencies.

Comment: @escaping closure means that call to this closure can be done when the function returned. Meaning you can't do this in this way. Closure can store local variable and i don't know but in c++ there exists something like promise and future. With these objects you can wait for variable and in another thread store variable. You should find something like that in swift.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you described cannot be solved that easily, because you basically run an async function inside of a sync function.

Some possible solutions:

1. If you use iOS 15 only, you could use async await (https://azamsharp.medium.com/getting-started-with-async-await-in-ios-27ec3213d43f)
2. You could use combine -> you would rewrite your async function to be combine and in the parent function you would sink() for the result and set some property - this would also be completely different code than your initial intention
3. Maybe it could be achieved via DispatchGroups - https://blog.vishalvshekkar.com/swift-dispatchgroup-an-effortless-way-to-handle-unrelated-asynchronous-operations-together-5d4d50b570c6